# The most suitable and secure way to include remote PHP code/ file

Tags: php, file, security, cross-domain, require

I have designed a php app and to prevent clients from copying I'm hosting critical part of this app on my servers. This could be either a php file, mysql database or smt.

Let's say the critical part is this

```
$var = 8;
```

Without this code, the app will never run. I want to have this file with this code on my server and domain "mydomainx.com"

Then I want to include this file from client's domain "clientsdomain.com". I've tried to do just

```
require ("http://mydomainx.com/myfile.php");
```

But that works only if the server allows http-s requires, and that is very uncommon.

Also I want to block every other domain from accesing this file, so smt like this

```
    $allow = array("myclient IP");

if(!in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $allow) && !in_array($_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"], $allow)) {
```

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: put the files in your root directory, so no one can access them

Answer (score 0):

make a folder named "incudes" out of the web-root directory and put all the include files on it,
to block direct access to the whole includes folder put a `.htaccess` in that folder and write in it

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from <your ip>
```

in this way you can include the files but you cannot open them